# Constructing real symmetric matrix with specific eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

How can I construct a real symmetric matrix $A$ that has eigenvalues $\{\frac{1}{m},\frac{2}{m},\ldots,1\}$ where $m$ is some number I specify?

I tried doing a few things like constructing symmetric matrix $P$ and then taking $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues I want on the diagonal. This didn't work.

I also tried constructing a random matrix $P$ and then taking $A=PDP^{-1}(PDP^{-1})^T$. This also didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A diagonal matrix with your eigenvalues on the diagonal ***is*** a real symmetric matrix having these eigenvalues. You don't seem to be satisfied with that. Why?

Comment: @IvanNeretin That would definitely satisfy what I am looking for, but I am trying to use this matrix for some numerical experiments with the Conjugate residual algorithm, but the algorithm becomes much simpler if I assume the matrix equation $Ax=b$ has $A$ being diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the diagonal matrix $D$ with the selected eigenvalues will be symmetrical. You can also rotate it by any [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) $P$, this will not change the eigenvalues and it will stay symmetrical. In general, you have $A=PDP^T$.

It's easy to prove it's symmetrical using transpose properties as $(PDP^T)^T=PD^TP^T$, knowing that $D$ is a diagonal matrix (so it's symmetrical too).

Comment: Great thanks for this! This is very clear!